# Regarding the expression “quoi que ce soit”

Tags: expressions, pronoms, pronoms-impersonnels

I want to express the idea of "if anything were to happen to that child" in colloquial French, and I wonder why "**il**" can serve as a subject in Version 1. Are these two versions nuanced at all?

- Version 1:

  > S'**il** arrivait **quoi que ce soit** à cette enfant, ...
- Version 2:

  > Si **quoi que ce soit** arrivait à cette enfant, ...

Comment: At first sight, they are both correct and mean exactly the same thing... Be aware that if you use "**cette** enfant", it implies it is a girl.

Comment: I would prefer and recommend the version 1. I found it more natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Les deux formes sont exactes.**

La 1 est une version *impersonnelle* de la 2, qui peut se construire avec des verbes qui indiquent un *événement*, quelque chose qui *survient*:

> Une personne arrive => Il arrive une personne.
>
> Un drame survient => Il survient un drame.
>
> De la neige tombe => Il tombe de la neige.

Exemple d'autres verbes: *apparaît*, *entrer*, *venir*, ...

Answer (score 1):

Your sentences mean what you want to say.

If you choose to use "quoi que ce soit" as a common name (V1), then you need to add a pronoun to say your condition.

Litterally, the translation is "If it happened anything..." but with the elision, you write "S'il".

V1 is more formal, V2 is in common language.